# WordPress: user meta won't grab PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, metadata

I am trying to get this meta data to display:

```
public static function user_register($user_id) {
    //The user_id is grabbed from wordpress and this is run after user 
    //registration, echo does display correctly the user_id as 806 (example)

    //$data = empty.. which makes no sense!!
    $data = get_user_meta ( $user_id , 'business', true );

    //Everything undernearth runs as it should..
    $grID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_id FROM wp_groups_group WHERE name = '$data'");
    Groups_User_Group::create( array( 'user_id' => $user_id, 'group_id' => $grID ));
}
```

Some confirmations:
Yes! setting variable `$data = "806";` does fix it!
**However**, this variable changes... I can't have a static string (806) for this. It has to be the current user.
The database is correct, there is a meta for business and the value is set (DB also seems to be fine)

`user_id == 806` (confirmed with testing below)

```
public static function user_register( $user_id ) {
    if($user_id == 806){
        $data = "806";
    }
    $grID = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT group_id FROM wp_groups_group WHERE name = '$data'");
    Groups_User_Group::create( array( 'user_id' => $user_id, 'group_id' => $grID ));
}
```

Other scripts that I have tried replacing `$data` with:

```
$data = get_user_meta ( get_current_user_id() , 'business', true );
```

and

```
$usr = get_current_user_id();
$data = get_user_meta ( $usr , 'business', true );
```

Comment: `get_current_user_id()` will return you current user id or zero if user isn't logged in. Dump `$usr` variable to see what you get. Your code looks good.

Comment: Here are the results for my modified version of dumping:

throw new Exception('Oh no, an exception! ' . var_dump($user_id, true) . var_dump($data, true). var_dump($grID, true));

int(824) bool(true) string(0) "" bool(true) NULL bool(true) as you can see in this, it does display the id correctly, but when it gets to $data it displays string(0)